# How to get access to session and other webcontext from MVC 6 TagHelper class?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

I need to either call some controller/action method or atleast call my own helper methods which will make use of session variable. How do i do this from within the Process method of TagHelper

Answer (score 3):

The `ViewContextAttribute` will provide access to the context (objects and such) that are also available to your View inside of your Tag Helper.

Inside of your tag helper class, add:

```
[ViewContext]
public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }
```

... then, you can create properties for use in the remainder of your tag helper to get to specific resources, like:

```
protected HttpRequest Request => ViewContext.HttpContext.Request;
protected HttpResponse Response => ViewContext.HttpContext.Response;
protected ISession Session => ViewContext.HttpContext.Session;
protected ITempDataDictionary TempData => ViewContext.TempData;
```

And then use them from within your Process method:

In my case, I needed to pass values between a parent (enclosing) tag helper and a child (enclosed) tag helper.  I could have created a custom object and injected into both, but since there is a tiny possibility I'll make this into a NuGet package, I didn't want to burden my users to set this DI up in their startup.cs.

So, I added this in the Process() method of the parent Tag Helper:

```
TempData.Set("Test", "Passed the test!");
```

... and then added this in the child Tag Helper:

```
object result;
if (TempData.TryGetValue("Test", out result))
{
  string success = result.ToString();
}
```

... and it worked.  I used TempData, but it depends on Session.  You can do the same thing with Session.

Comment: Here's a thread containing a list of other attributes used to inject context specific types:  https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4744